# que significa " return 32; "en c?

Tags: c, funciones, basic

Este es el ejercicio,solo queria saber a que se refiere con:

> return 32;

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int bits(unsigned int n);
int main()
{
    unsigned int n=7,j;
    j=bits(n);
    printf("%d",j);

    return 0;
}

int bits(unsigned int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return 32;
    }
        else
        {
            if(n&1==1)
            {
                return 1+bits(n>>1);
                }
            else
            {
                return bits(n>>1);
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Significa que regresa el valor entero 32

Comment: Pero para que?Yo en todo caso  pondria return 0; y listo no veo la necesidad de que devuevuelva ese numero 32..Es cualquier cosa el ejemplo jaja

Comment: Por el contexto de la función, se supone que tiene que contar bits, el `return 32;` indica que hay 32 bits apagados _(Adivinando un poco tu ejercicio)_ y que por ende, retorna la cantidad de bits; ahí termina la recursividad, pero ese código no tiene tanto sentido.

Comment: Si yo tampoco ,igualmente si  remplazo el 32 por un 0 el ejercicio funciona bien también.

Comment: Se trata de una función recursiva la que tienes en tu pregunta y por lo tanto n == 0 se trata del caso base de la recursión. Una pregunta correcta sería: Cuál es el propósito de la función bits. Por lo que se ve, lo que hace es examinar una cifra de enteros bit a bit, aumentando en 1 por cada bit encendido, o dicho propiamente, con valor de '1'. Una vez que ya no hay 1s suma a la cuenta 32. Podrías indicar cuál es la salida que aparece en pantalla? Al parecer será 35.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función bits entrega la cantidad de bits en 1; que contiene la representación binaria del numero `n`.

En este caso, es una función recursiva que los va contando. Se puede notar que efectivamente cuenta los bits en 1, dado el caso iterativo. Sin embargo, el caso base debería entregar un 0. Esto dado que 32 es el caso que todos los bits son 1; y eso solo debería ocurrir cuando n es el unsigned int máximo.

Si fuera tu, probaría la función con distintos valores de n, y comparándolos con sus valores esperados. Si te entrega valores erróneos, cambiaría el 32 por un 0 y volvería a comprobar.
Seguramente sea un error.

Saludos,